# Consumer Processing Timeout?

Tags: solace

Here is our scenario:

We are publishing messages to a topic, and have a queue subscribed to that topic. We have several node.js consumers connected to that queue to process incoming messages, via the solclient package.

What we want to do is process the incoming messages, and after successfully processing the message, acknowledge the message so that it is removed from the queue. The challenge we're having is how to deal with error conditions. We are trying to figure out how to flag to the broker that the message failed to be processed? The expectation would be that the broker would then attempt to send to a consumer again, and once max redeliveries is hit, it moves to the DMQ.

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe there's a way in Solace for a consumer to "NACK" a received message to signal an error in processing.  I believe your option would be to unbind from the queue (i.e. `disconnect()` the Flow object, or `MessageConsumer` in the Node.js API) which will place allow any unacknowledged messages back on the queue and available for redelivery, and then rebind to the queue.

Alternatively, if you do your processing in the message received callback method, you could throw an exception in there, and that should (?) accomplish the same thing.  But probably a lot less graceful.

https://docs.solace.com/Solace-PubSub-Messaging-APIs/Developer-Guide/Creating-Flows.htm

https://docs.solace.com/API-Developer-Online-Ref-Documentation/js/solace.MessageConsumer.html#disconnect